# extracting content of content attribute in meta tag of a website given a specified value for the name attribute with nokogiri in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

My first question here, would be awesome to find an answer. I am new to using nokogiri.

Here is my problem. I have something like this in the HTML head on a target site (here a techcrunch post):

```
<meta content="During my time at TechCrunch I've seen thousands of startups and written about hundreds of them. I sure as hell don't know all ..." name="description"/>
```

I would now like to have a script to run through the meta tags, locate the one with the name attribute "description" and get what is in the content attribute.

I have tried something like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/10/11/the-underutilized-power-of-the-video-demo-to-explain-what-the-hell-you-actually-do/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
posts = doc.xpath("//meta")
posts.each do |link|
  a = link.attributes['name']
  b = link.attributes['content']
end
```

after which I could select the link where the attribute name is equal to description - but this code returns nil for a and b.

I played around with
`posts = doc.xpath("//meta")`, `posts = doc.xpath("//meta/*")`, etc. but still nil.

Comment: The problem is not with the xpath, as it seems the document does not parse. You can check that with `puts doc`, it does not contain the full input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the xpath, as it seems the document does not parse. You can check that with `puts doc`, it does not contain the full input. It seems to be a problem with parsing comments (I suspect either invalid HTML or a bug in libxml2).

In your case I would use a regular expression as *workaround*. Given that `<meta>` tags are simple enough that might work, eg `/<meta name="([^"]*)" content="([^"]*)"/`

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

to

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
```

update: or maybe not :) actually your code works for me, using ruby 1.8.7 / nokogiri 1.4.0